# How to Clone and manage a virtual machine in Azure using C# and Azure .Net SDK?

Tags: c#, azure, virtual-machine

I have followed the guidelines on [how to manage virtual machines using C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-csharp-manage?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-machines%2Fwindows%2Ftoc.json) and could create a sample program based on it.

However, In addition I have a use case where we want to clone multiple virtual machines and manage them remotely using a console program written in C#. I could find the ways to [clone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-vhd-copy) a VM via power shell, but I could not find anywhere how can I create a clone and eventually manage the cloned VM on Azure.

Can anyone please give me  a direction on how I can use .Net SDK to achieve this use case?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Compute https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn722415.aspx  https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Compute/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do that with [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent) and [WindowsAzure.Storage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/).

I create a demo for it and it works correctly for me. The following is my detail steps.

As you mentioned [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-vhd-copy). Firstly we need to deallocate the VM. Before that we need to get authentication to operation resource in the Azure.

1.Get Azure object using an authentication file, how to create an authentication file please refer to [document](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/Fluent/AUTH.md). Before that we need to registry an Azure AD Application and assign corresponding role for it, more details please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#create-an-active-directory-application). Then we can get the clientId, key(secret key) and tenant from the Azure AD App. The file format as following

```
subscription=########-####-####-####-############
client=########-####-####-####-############
key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
tenant=########-####-####-####-############
managementURI=https\://management.core.windows.net/
baseURL=https\://management.azure.com/
authURL=https\://login.windows.net/
graphURL=https\://graph.windows.net/
```

Create the Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent.Azure object

```
 var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromFile(@"path of authentication file");

 var azure = Azure

                .Configure()

                .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.BASIC)

                .Authenticate(credentials)

                .WithDefaultSubscription()
```

2.Deallocate the VM with C# code.

```
azure.VirtualMachines.PowerOff(resourcegroup,vmName);  //shutdown the VM
azure.VirtualMachines.Deallocate(resourcegroup, vmName); //deallocate the VM
```

3.Get the VM Disk Vhd uri Info with code

```
 var vm = azure.VirtualMachines.GetByGroup(resourcegroup, vmName);
 string vhdUri= vm.StorageProfile.OsDisk.Vhd.Uri;  //result :  https://storageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/blob.vhd
```

4.From the vhduri then we can get **Storage Account** and **blobname**.

5.Start to copy blob to the target container, more details about operating blob please refer to the document.

```
        var account = azure.StorageAccounts.GetByGroup(resourcegroup,storageaccount);

        var key = account.GetKeys()[0];

        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("connectionstring");
        // Create a CloudFileClient object for credentialed access to File storage.
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("tomvhds");
        CloudBlobContainer sourceBlobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("vhds");
        container.CreateIfNotExists();
        CloudPageBlob destBlob = container.GetPageBlobReference(destinationBlob);
        CloudPageBlob sourcePageBlob = sourceBlobContainer.GetPageBlobReference(sourceblob);
        destBlob.StartCopy(sourcePageBlob);
        copyVhdurl =  destBlob.Uri.ToString();
```

6.Create the Disk for creating vm

```
 var disk = azure.Disks.Define("diskname") 
               .WithRegion(location)
               .WithExistingResourceGroup(resourcegroup)
               .WithWindowsFromVhd(copyvhduri)
               .Create();
```

7.Create  the VM and check from the Azure portal

```
 var windowsVm = azure.VirtualMachines.Define(machinename)

                   .WithRegion(location)  //eastasia

                   .WithNewResourceGroup(resourcegroupName)

                   .WithNewPrimaryNetwork("10.0.0.0/28")

                   .WithPrimaryPrivateIpAddressDynamic()

                   .WithNewPrimaryPublicIpAddress("dnslab")

                   .WithSpecializedOsDisk(disk, OperatingSystemTypes.Windows)

                   .WithSize(VirtualMachineSizeTypes.StandardA0)

                   .Create();
```

[image]

[image]

packages.config file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.AppService.Fluent" version="1.0.0-beta50" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Batch.Fluent" version="1.0.0-beta50" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Cdn.Fluent" version="1.0.0-beta50" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Fluent" version="1.0.0-beta50" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Dns.Fluent" version="1.0.0-beta50" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent" version="1.0.0-beta50" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Graph.RBAC.Fluent" version="1.0.0-beta50" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.KeyVault.Fluent" version="1.0.0-beta50" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Network.Fluent" version="1.0.0-beta50" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Redis.Fluent" version="1.0.0-beta50" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent" version="1.0.0-beta50" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql.Fluent" version="1.0.0-beta50" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage.Fluent" version="1.0.0-beta50" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.TrafficManager.Fluent" version="1.0.0-beta50" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Edm" version="5.8.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.OData" version="5.8.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Services.Client" version="5.8.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" version="2.28.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime" version="2.3.5" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure" version="3.3.5" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure.Authentication" version="2.2.10" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.8" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync" version="4.0.11" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Dynamic.Runtime" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Linq.Queryable" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Net.Requests" version="4.0.11" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Spatial" version="5.8.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="WindowsAzure.Storage" version="8.1.1" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

Comment: wow ..thanks a lot, yesterday I could do all this via PowerShell and I will today try this via code using your example. However, I was initially a bit susceptible to use fluent api because perhaps it is still not fully developed? I was using the code used in the link and that seems to be not using fluent. However, would you suggest me to start using fluent for managing vms in my code?

Comment: As you mentioned that it is a beta version SDK. But it is easy for to manage vms such as poweroff ,start, restart and etc. If you find issue about it, you could give your feedback for it. If you are very susceptible about beta version, please pay attention to released version.

Comment: OK thanks a lot, I should follow it and let you know !