# Azure - Create a virtual machine from a snapshot with C#

Tags: c#, powershell, azure, virtual-machine, snapshot

This page contains instructions for creating an Azure virtual machine from a snapshot with PowerShell:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/scripts/virtual-machines-windows-powershell-sample-create-vm-from-snapshot?toc=%2fpowershell%2fmodule%2ftoc.json

Is there a way to do this in C#?

There is a documented way to clone in C# but this requires the VHD to be in the cloud. How to convert a disk image into a page blob (the VHD) is a different topic.  The only way I know how now is to export the image to my local drive as a VHD file and then upload it to a page blob - this is way too slow, it takes days to export and re-upload.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/csharp..... see if it helps.

Comment: I started out with that page to create a vm in C# and it works great but the description doesn't get as far as creating a vm from an existing vm.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Clone and manage a virtual machine in Azure using C# and Azure .Net SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42933466/how-to-clone-and-manage-a-virtual-machine-in-azure-using-c-sharp-and-azure-net)

Comment: I went to this page and can successfully clone in C# but it requires that the VHD be in the cloud.  I don't know how to get a VHD in the cloud other than to create a disk image, export it to my local drive as a VHD and then upload it to a page blob.  This download/upload is 15 days each way (and I have decent network speed).  I cancelled when it said 15 days to export.  How to copy a disk image in the cloud to a page blob is another topic.

Answer (score 0):

Select the snapshot in the Azure portal.
Click Automation script.
Click .NET to see C# code to deploy using the image.